# Is it correct fronting subject complement?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct fronting subject complement in the first place in a sentence? E.g to turn "It's a very good camera" into "a very good camera it is"

Comment: Yes, you could in the right situation. For example, you may be discussing the camera and say "And a very good camera it is". It would only work, though, if the complement served as a link to the preceding discourse.

Comment: Yes, though to my Canadian ears, it sounds distinctly British.

Comment: Yes and no.  It is done informally, usually for emphasis (like "*Five hundred dollars* they wanted for it!") but it is not standard; you don't use this order unless you have a specific reason to.